# Is there any reason glUseProgram might crash my program? (C Win32)

Tags: c, winapi, opengl

I'm learning OpenGL with Win32 in C and I've just gotten to the point where I want to implement shaders. I'm doing this more as a learning experience rather than a project, so I decided not to use a typical extension wrangler library like glew or something. Here is my extension grabber header file:

glExtensions.h:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB         0x2001
#define WGL_ACCELERATION_ARB           0x2003
#define WGL_SWAP_METHOD_ARB            0x2007
#define WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB         0x2010
#define WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB          0x2011
#define WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB             0x2013
#define WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB             0x2014
#define WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB             0x2022
#define WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB           0x2023
#define WGL_FULL_ACCELERATION_ARB      0x2027
#define WGL_SWAP_EXCHANGE_ARB          0x2028
#define WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB              0x202B
#define WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB  0x2091
#define WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB  0x2092
#define GL_ARRAY_BUFFER                   0x8892
#define GL_STATIC_DRAW                    0x88E4
#define GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER                0x8B30
#define GL_VERTEX_SHADER                  0x8B31
#define GL_COMPILE_STATUS                 0x8B81
#define GL_LINK_STATUS                    0x8B82
#define GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH                0x8B84
#define GL_TEXTURE0                       0x84C0
#define GL_BGRA                           0x80E1
#define GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER           0x8893

PROC glCreateProgram;
PROC glCreateShader;
PROC glShaderSource;
PROC glCompileShader;
PROC glAttachShader;
PROC glLinkProgram;
PROC glUseProgram;
PROC glGetShaderInfoLog;
PROC glDeleteShader;
PROC glDetachShader;
PROC glIsProgram;
PROC glGenBuffers;
PROC glBindBuffer;
PROC glBufferData;
PROC glEnableVertexAttribArray;
PROC glVertexAttribPointer;
PROC glGenVertexArrays;
PROC glBindVertexArray;

void GLEInit(int);
```

and here is the c file,
glExtionsions.c

```
#include "glExtensions.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include "consoleUtil.h"

extern PROC glCreateProgram;
extern PROC glCreateShader;
extern PROC glShaderSource;
extern PROC glCompileShader;
extern PROC glAttachShader;
extern PROC glLinkProgram;
extern PROC glUseProgram;
extern PROC glGetShaderInfoLog;
extern PROC glDeleteShader;
extern PROC glDetachShader;
extern PROC glIsProgram;
extern PROC glGenBuffers;
extern PROC glBindBuffer;
extern PROC glBufferData;
extern PROC glEnableVertexAttribArray;
extern PROC glVertexAttribPointer;
extern PROC glGenVertexArrays;
extern PROC glBindVertexArray;

PROC getProc(int hOut, const char* name) {
    PROC p = wglGetProcAddress(name);
    if(p == 0 ||
        (p == (void*)0x1) || (p == (void*)0x2) || (p == (void*)0x3) ||
        (p == (void*)-1) )
    {
        HMODULE module = LoadLibraryA("opengl32.dll");
        p = GetProcAddress(module, name);
    }

    return p;
}

void GLEInit(int hOut) {
    glCreateProgram = getProc(hOut, "glCreateProgram");
    glCreateShader = getProc(hOut, "glCreateShader");
    glShaderSource = getProc(hOut, "glShaderSource");
    glCompileShader = getProc(hOut, "glCompileShader");
    glAttachShader = getProc(hOut, "glAttachShader");
    glLinkProgram = getProc(hOut, "glLinkProgram");
    glUseProgram = getProc(hOut, "glUseProgram");
    glGetShaderInfoLog = getProc(hOut, "glGetShaderInfoLog");
    glDeleteShader = getProc(hOut, "glDeleteShader");
    glDetachShader = getProc(hOut, "glDetachShader");
    glIsProgram = getProc(hOut, "glIsProgram");
    glGenBuffers = getProc(hOut, "glGenBuffers");
    glBindBuffer = getProc(hOut, "glBindBuffer");
    glBufferData = getProc(hOut, "glBufferData");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray = getProc(hOut, "glEnableVertexAttribArray");
    glVertexAttribPointer = getProc(hOut, "glVertexAttribPointer");
    glGenVertexArrays = getProc(hOut, "glGenVertexArrays");
    glBindVertexArray = getProc(hOut, "glBindVertexArray");
}
```

GLEInit is run just after the window is created, then I run this code

```
int createBasicProgram(int hOut) {
    //vertex shader bullcrap
    FILE* basicVSFile = getFile("shaders/basic.vs");
    FILEDATA* vsfd = getFileData(hOut, basicVSFile);
    close(basicVSFile);

    int vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vs, vsfd->numLines, vsfd->lines, vsfd->lengths);
    glCompileShader(vs);

    int actualLength = 0;
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vs, ERROR_BUFFER_SIZE, &actualLength, errorBuffer);
    if (actualLength > 0) {
        print(hOut, "deleting vertex shader\n");
        glDeleteShader(vs);
        print(hOut, errorBuffer);
        return -1;
    }
    freeFileData(vsfd);


    //fragment shader bullcrap
    FILE* basicFSFile = getFile("shaders/basic.fs");
    FILEDATA* fsfd = getFileData(hOut, basicFSFile);
    int fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fs, fsfd->numLines, fsfd->lines, fsfd->lengths);
    glCompileShader(fs);

    glGetShaderInfoLog(fs, ERROR_BUFFER_SIZE, &actualLength, errorBuffer);
    if (actualLength > 0) {
        print(hOut, "deleting fragment shader\n");
        glDeleteShader(fs);
        print(hOut, errorBuffer);
        return -1;
    }
    freeFileData(fsfd);

    int progId = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(progId, vs);
    glAttachShader(progId, fs);
    glLinkProgram(progId);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(progId, ERROR_BUFFER_SIZE, &actualLength, errorBuffer);
    if (actualLength > 0) {
        print(hOut, errorBuffer);
    }

    glDetachShader(progId, vs);
    glDetachShader(progId, fs);
    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return progId;
}

void init(hOut) {
    bp = createBasicProgram(hOut);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoId);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

this code causes no errors, yet when I add the simple statement:

```
glUseProgram(bp);
```

into the display function, which is called every frame, the program runs for a second, the console and program window open and are black for like 3 seconds, and then crash with no build errors or output errors to trace. Is there any reason this glUseProgram would cause my program to crash?

The stack dump says: "Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=001004016E6", with a bunch of memory locations and stuff I don't understand.

Comment: You for sure query the wrong error log after linking. Should be `glGetProgramInfoLog` instead of `glGetShaderInfoLog`.

Comment: Well, what's this crazy stuff for? `if(p == 0 ||
        (p == (void*)0x1) || (p == (void*)0x2) || (p == (void*)0x3) ||
        (p == (void*)-1) )`. Note that void pointers and function pointers cannot be mixed reliably.

Comment: Please also describe what "crash" means in your context. Does the program simply closes itself without any message? No "unable to execute location ..." error?

Comment: Saying a "crash" gives us very little to go off of. If the program truly does crash, there has to be a log someplace of that error.

Comment: According to the manual for wglGetProcAddress: "When no current rendering context exists or the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError." Keep `if(p == 0)` and drop that other crap, to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @Lundin: "*what's this crazy stuff for?*" The WGL function pointer retrieval function does not reliably return `nullptr` for functions that aren't provided by the implementation. It can return a plethora of invalid pointer values, so you have to check the pointer against all such values. Now, this was almost certainly copied from another loader, who copied it from a different loader, etc, so it's not clear if this is still necessary on implementations today, but it was needed at some point.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok well "gut debugging" says that the bug is almost certainly located in `getProc`. Not checking the result of LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress is equally smelly. GetProcAddress in particular easily fails.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you are learning, invest time into learning how to use a debugger. That's time well spent. It's the tool you will be using more than any other tool.

Comment: @Lundin, the crazy stuff was from the OpenGL wiki: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions , I just copied what they had, figured it couldn't get much better.

Comment: @potatopotato Evidently that is not a reliable source for how to write stable C programs then. You cannot compare function pointers with void pointers, simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent another 7 hours working on this project and I've finally figured it out. By "it", I mean there are several things that were wrong with my old code. The first two issues were glExtensions.c and glExtensions.h, Originally all I had done was call used getProc to get a function pointer and put it in a PROC macro, which is not at all what it needs to be. PROC doesn't use the correct calling convention or specify the correct parameters, instead you need to include glext.h, which is maintained by khronos and can be found here: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/api/GL/glext.h . A description as to what these functions do can also be found here: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions . The other thing that needed to change was glUseProgram was called before the program was created. The program creation code was correct, however I was calling display on WM_PAINT and WM_SIZE, and both of which are put into the message queue and handled before GLEInit was called. Instead, display should be called in the message loop if PeekMessage cannot find any messages.

Here is the relevant code that's been changed since last time:

glExtensions.h:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "glext.h"
#include "wglext.h"

PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC glCreateProgram;
PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC glCreateShader;
PFNGLSHADERSOURCEPROC glShaderSource;
PFNGLCOMPILESHADERPROC glCompileShader;
PFNGLATTACHSHADERPROC glAttachShader;
PFNGLLINKPROGRAMPROC glLinkProgram;
PFNGLUSEPROGRAMPROC glUseProgram;
PFNGLGETSHADERINFOLOGPROC glGetShaderInfoLog;
PFNGLGETPROGRAMINFOLOGPROC glGetProgramInfoLog;
PFNGLDELETESHADERPROC glDeleteShader;
PFNGLDETACHSHADERPROC glDetachShader;
PFNGLISPROGRAMPROC glIsProgram;
PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC glGenBuffers;
PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC glBindBuffer;
PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC glBufferData;
PFNGLENABLEVERTEXATTRIBARRAYPROC glEnableVertexAttribArray;
PFNGLVERTEXATTRIBPOINTERPROC glVertexAttribPointer;
PFNGLGENVERTEXARRAYSPROC glGenVertexArrays;
PFNGLBINDVERTEXARRAYPROC glBindVertexArray;
PFNGLGETINTEGERI_VPROC glGetIntegeri_v;
PFNGLGETSTRINGIPROC glGetStringi;
PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC wglSwapIntervalEXT;
PFNWGLGETSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC wglGetSwapIntervalEXT;

void GLEInit(HANDLE);

void checkGLError(HANDLE, char*);
```

glExtensions.c:

```
#include "glExtensions.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include "consoleUtil.h"

void* getProc(HANDLE hOut, const char* name) {
    print(hOut, "loading %s\n", name);
    void* p = wglGetProcAddress(name);
    if (p == NULL) {
        int e = GetLastError();
        print(hOut, "error loading %s: %i\n", name, e);
        return NULL;
    }
    if(p == 0 ||
        (p == (void*)0x1) || (p == (void*)0x2) || (p == (void*)0x3) ||
        (p == (void*)-1) )
    {
        HMODULE module = LoadLibraryA("opengl32.dll");
        if (module == NULL) {
            int e = GetLastError();
            print(hOut, "error loading library \"opengl32.dll\" for function pointer %s: %i\n", name, e);
            return NULL;
        }
        p = GetProcAddress(module, name);
        if (p == NULL) {
            int e = GetLastError();
            print(hOut, "error loading %s with getProcAddress: %i\n", name, e);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    print(hOut, "success loading\n");
    return p;
}

void checkGLError(HANDLE hOut, char* desc) {
    GLenum e = glGetError();
    if (e > 0) {
        print(hOut, "Error %i: %s\n", e, desc);
        return;
    }
    print(hOut, "%s completed with no errors\n", desc);
}

void GLEInit(HANDLE hOut) {
    glCreateProgram = (PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC)getProc(hOut, "glCreateProgram");
    glCreateShader = (PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC)getProc(hOut, "glCreateShader");
    glShaderSource = (PFNGLSHADERSOURCEPROC)getProc(hOut, "glShaderSource");
    glCompileShader = (PFNGLCOMPILESHADERPROC)getProc(hOut, "glCompileShader");
    glAttachShader = (PFNGLATTACHSHADERPROC)getProc(hOut, "glAttachShader");
    glLinkProgram = (PFNGLLINKPROGRAMPROC)getProc(hOut, "glLinkProgram");
    glUseProgram = (PFNGLUSEPROGRAMPROC)getProc(hOut, "glUseProgram");
    glGetShaderInfoLog = (PFNGLGETSHADERINFOLOGPROC)getProc(hOut, "glGetShaderInfoLog");
    glGetProgramInfoLog = (PFNGLGETPROGRAMINFOLOGPROC)getProc(hOut, "glGetProgramInfoLog");
    glDeleteShader = (PFNGLDELETESHADERPROC)getProc(hOut, "glDeleteShader");
    glDetachShader = (PFNGLDETACHSHADERPROC)getProc(hOut, "glDetachShader");
    glIsProgram = (PFNGLISPROGRAMPROC)getProc(hOut, "glIsProgram");
    glGenBuffers = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC)getProc(hOut, "glGenBuffers");
    glBindBuffer = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC)getProc(hOut, "glBindBuffer");
    glBufferData = (PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC)getProc(hOut, "glBufferData");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray = (PFNGLENABLEVERTEXATTRIBARRAYPROC)getProc(hOut, "glEnableVertexAttribArray");
    glVertexAttribPointer = (PFNGLVERTEXATTRIBPOINTERPROC)getProc(hOut, "glVertexAttribPointer");
    glGenVertexArrays = (PFNGLGENVERTEXARRAYSPROC)getProc(hOut, "glGenVertexArrays");
    glBindVertexArray = (PFNGLBINDVERTEXARRAYPROC)getProc(hOut, "glBindVertexArray");
    glGetIntegeri_v = (PFNGLGETINTEGERI_VPROC)getProc(hOut, "glGetIntegeri_v");
    glGetStringi = (PFNGLGETSTRINGIPROC)getProc(hOut, "glGetStringi");
    wglSwapIntervalEXT = (PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC)getProc(hOut, "wglSwapIntervalEXT");
    wglGetSwapIntervalEXT = (PFNWGLGETSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC)getProc(hOut, "wglGetSwapIntervalEXT");
}
```

Comment: So the bug was partially in some Windows WndProc message loop not posted?

Comment: once I'd fixed my extension loader files, the issue was when I called ShowWindow(hWnd), it was inserting a WM_SIZE and WM_PAINT into the message queue, which was called the display function. The reason this threw an error was because I hadn't called GLEInit() until after I Showed the window, and the shader program was created in GLEInit(). Because of this, the first display function was telling opengl to use a program that didn't exist, which gave me a seg fault and caused a crash.